# Can't Build .apk in Android studio 1.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, gimbal

Currently i am trying to run a sample application "Hello Gimbal Android" using Android Studio 1.3 (updated 28 july 2015)

After follow step by step from tutorial :

1. Clone sample application from github.
2. Import project in Android Studio
3. Fill in the API key in MainActivity file.
4. Add the jars from the Gimbal SDK libs directory to the project libs directory
5. Last step is build the project (using **Build** -> **Make Project**)

It is successfully built as shown in grandle console but after that i search it cant find the .apk file.

Anyone has this experience before? Any clue?

```
Executing tasks: [:app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJava
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.7 secs
```

Note :

I use ubuntu 14.04, have downloaded the Android SDK and also have configured the PATH.

Comment: Have you check the `\<project-name>\build\outputs\apk` folder in package structure ?

Comment: Yes. I've check that directory but there's nothing

Comment: Did you try re-building your project ?

Comment: I just build the project without Run the app before. Thats the problem. I've found the answer from comment by @Eran below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just build, you don't get an apk.

**For an unsigned apk** you need to either
 - Run the app (Run > Run "YourProject")
 - Execute assemble Task from Gradle panel (present in right hand side of the
Studio window) or from the embedded terminal window on bottom (in project Root)

Then the apk is in `$YOUR_PROJECT/$YOUR_MODULE/build/outputs/apk`

**For a signed apk**, use Build -> Generate Signed APK

Comment: Perfect answer! Now i realize why i can't find the .apk. I just build after import an sample app. Many thanks, @Eran!

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the `Gradle` Console `Rebuild Project` will say something like...:

[See here. Perhaps help you...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30654442/4813855)