# Make Project vs Build Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm confusing what is the difference between android "Make Project" and "ReBuild Project". Is there anyone knows this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean "Rebuild Project"?

Comment: Different between Rebuild and Make project

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20376100/3922207

Answer (score 0):

I use command line tools to build Android apps, and the difference for me is that I can run a new build that will tell me if there are any errors in my code or missing files that I've linked to for some reason. After a successful build, I run a make, which *makes* a version of the app that I can run and test.